# DynamicMethod call terminated due to a StackOverFlowException

Tags: c#, dynamicmethod, ilgenerator

I have this class (simplified example)

```
public class Foo
{
    public object Bar(Type type)
    {
        return new object();
    }
}
```

and I want to call the `Bar` method **on an instance of `Bar`** using `DynamicMethod` as it is shown below:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Foo).GetMethod(nameof(Foo.Bar), new[] { typeof(Type) });
DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("Dynamic Bar", 
                                         typeof(object), 
                                         new []{ typeof(Type) }, 
                                         typeof(Foo).Module);

ILGenerator ilGenerator = method.GetILGenerator();
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilGenerator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, method, null); // I feel like this is wrong...
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

Func<Type, object> func = (Func<Type, object>) method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Type, object>));

// Attempt to call the function:
func(typeof(Foo));
```

However, it does not work as wanted but rather aborts with

> Process is terminated due to a StackOverFlowException.

---

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Is it a mismatch of the parameters?
How can I call the `Func` on a specific instance of `Bar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ilGenerator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, method, null); // I feel like this is wrong...
```

You are currently *writing* `method`; you probably intended to call `methodInfo` here. Note that this will need to be a `static` method to use `Call` - if it is an instance method, you should probably be using `CallVirt`. Since you aren't passing in an instance of `Foo`, it is unclear where the target instance is going to come from; you need to load **two** values onto the stack to call the instance method `Foo.Bar(Type type)` - and you're currently only loading one.

To show `Delegate.CreateDelegate` usage:

```
var methodInfo = typeof(Foo).GetMethod(nameof(Foo.Bar), new[] { typeof(Type) });
var foo = new Foo();

// if Foo is known ahead of time:
var f1 = (Func<Type, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Func<Type, object>), foo, methodInfo);

// if Foo is only known per-call:
var f2 = (Func<Foo, Type, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Func<Foo, Type, object>), null, methodInfo);

Console.WriteLine(f1(typeof(string)));

Console.WriteLine(f2(foo, typeof(string)));
```

Comment: `CallVirt` seems promising, as I want the method to be called on a specific instance. Thank you for the hint. Also, I would rather not use `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, because it prove to be kind of a performance bottleneck before.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow compared to DynamicMethod? I think (based on over a decade of IL-emit work) that you're probably not going to get improved performance by using ILGenerator/MethodBuilder.CreateDelegate instead of Delegate.CreateDelegate. Either of these approaches is very effective **as long as** you cache the generated instance correctly.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow also see my update about needing an instance of `Foo`

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. Right now I am using `MethodInfo.Invoke`, which is kind of slow. Therefore I was hoping to get improved performance by using IL. If I remember correctly, I used `MethodInfo.Invoke` as an improvement over `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, but I might be wrong here. Considering the instance of `Foo`, I was also wondering about where to put it. Could you please provide a little example on that? Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow no, Delegate.CreateDelegate is **very** different to `MethodInfo.Invoke`, with `Delegate.CreateDelegate` being **much** faster, *as long as* you store the delegate and don't create it per-call.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow well, where does the `Foo` instance come from? you can't "store" it on a `DynamicMethod` - there's nowhere to store it. Three options: you create a `Func<Foo, Type, object>` instead (and use arg0/arg1), or you create a `TypeBuilder` with a field, and a constructor that assigns the field, and use `ldarg0, ldfld_s {fld}, ldarg1`; or third option: `Delegate.CreateDelegate` **already takes a target instance**

Comment: Alright, thank you for that tip as well. I will look into that and see if it does improve performance in my case. Although I darkly remember that for some reason I couldn't use `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, I don't know what exactly it was anymore - I think generics. However, your post is a very good starting point, thank you very much.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow added full example of `Delegate.CreateDelegate` for both the scenarios (`Foo` known ahead of time, vs `Foo` known per-call)

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow the main time that `Delegate.CreateDelegate` doesn't work is if you need to do non-trivial conversions as part of the call

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow sorry to spam with replies, but the important thing with `Delegate.CreateDelegate` is: make sure you always write it to a typed delegate; if you just store it as `Delegate` and use `DynamicInvoke`, then sure: you haven't saved anything and might as well have used reflection `Invoke`

Comment: No need to be sorry, I am very happy for all your highly qualified replies. It might be that I used `DynamicInvoke` back then, which explains why it was slower.